# Are there ‘light’ users that don’t need a license?

Tags: userlicense

I’m salesforce crm is there the concept of a light user? Like in jira I’ve got users and customers, I have to license users but any customer can email in a question then participate in their specific tickets. Can I do that without having to create a custom ‘myuser’ object and manually populate it with all my domain users. I only want to be able to ‘assign’ them to a user picker field in my opportunities and cases. They don’t need actual access to the system or even to receive emails from it. Just a way for me to say this email from this list of emails goes here.

Comment: See Email-to-Case set up -- this generates a Case with an associated Contact for that incoming email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the surface of things, since you're talking about tracking email communication and not directly accessing Salesforce, I'd say the Contact object is an appropriate place for this.